# Unity3D Input Field shows "????????"

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

I am writing a game for Kazakhstan, but Kazakh symbols do not show in UI element InputField.

Did somebody face the problem and can help me?

Comment: People here can help you, if you show your code.

Comment: i am using standart unity user interface, element Input Field is created in editor window "UI->InputField".  What code do you want to see?

Answer (score 1):

An `UI_InputField` element is an element that allows the user to interact writing some text. `InputField` will set that text into a `UI_Text` component.

The `UI_Text` component supports UTF and you can set different fonts to that `UI_Text` component. Now in order to display correctly your Kazakh symbols the Font that is assigned to the `UI_Text` component should be able to support those characters.

So the first question is, what font are you using in your `UI_Text` component?

Here if I get some characters from [Kazakh_alphabets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazakh_alphabets) and I put them in a TextField/Text using `Arial` as font.
I got this:
[image: Example with Kazakh characters]

Comment: I use font which supports symbols of Kazakhstan. If i copy text "ңіғңі" then i see symbols correctly, but if i enter these symbols in InputField i see "???"

Comment: Thats weird, in my system (osx, Unity 5.6.0f3 it works if I copy & paste the values or if I change my the input keyboard to Kazakh). It could be a Unity bug.